# DirectX ID3DXAnimationController concept of an 'event'

Tags: directx

I'm currently using the ID3DXAnimationController interface, but have for some time not understood what the concept of an 'event' is that the controller seems to reference.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/bb205626(v=vs.85).aspx) and other references just seem to state this as some event running on the current track, without really mentioning what this means.

Would anyone be able to explain? (with concrete examples)

Answer (score 1):

An animation event is one of these types [D3DXEVENT_TYPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/bb172827.aspx).

> Remember that D3DX9 (along with D3DX10 and D3DX11) are deprecated. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)